# iOS In-App Purchase Offer Codes - Can user use a new offer code after subscription expires?

Tags: ios, apple-store, in-app-purchase

If I provide an offer code, for a 1-month of free subscription, to a user for free access to my app, after 1 month can the same user use the new code for a 1-month of free subscription?

OR

User can use the offer code only 1 time?

Answer (score 1):

Per [Apple Developer docs](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev6a098e4b1):

> Offer codes are unique, alphanumeric codes that provide a free or discounted price for auto-renewable subscriptions for a specific duration.  **Each offer code can be redeemed only once**. You can create a maximum of 150,000 codes per app, per quarter. In order for users to redeem your codes, they must be running iOS 14, or iPadOS 14 or later.

Also [here](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=dopmcbjk):

> Customers can redeem only one code per active offer, but may be eligible to redeem multiple different offer codes for a single subscription, depending on your configuration choices.

Comment: Yes but this is confusing. What if the user has new code again? Can they use it and have free subscription access?

Comment: That depends on how you code your application to the user's Apple ID.  It's in your control.

Comment: Actually, I want users to use a new code for free access next as well. But will Apple allow this for the same Apple ID?

Comment: They should, you control who gets codes and who doesn't based on if you code these as consumable or non-consumable IAP.  If you make the monthly access as a consumable IAP, they can keep getting the monthly access as long as they redeem the unique code.